# XMLHttpRequest returning extra characters

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

After making an `XMLHttpRequest()` I get the following "true↵↵↵", when in my php file I am only outputting the following `echo json_encode(true);`

Anybody knows the reason why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: You must ensure that in your PHP file there are no blank lines before or after on `<?php ?>` tags

Comment: post your php code. also make sure that nothing is printed other than the actual result in the php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the file you use to handle the XMLHttpRequest a php only file? If so, you don't need to end the file with the php closing tag:

```
?>
```

Removing this might prevent extra output from your file.

Also make sure that you don't have any extra output in your handling file (or any other files that are included in this file).

Comment: thanks for your help. I had some returns after the ?> php closing tag. If possible could anyone explain how that works.

Comment: A bit late maybe... But if you close the PHP script, any characters following the closed script are parsed as normal HTML.
This may cause extra unexpected output to your request results or output pages.